# the application launch collapses via android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

i am new to the community so please be patient. this is the logcat:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.linebet, PID: 7546
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.linebet/com.example.linebet.Register}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.linebet.Register> cannot be instantiated
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.linebet.Register> cannot be instantiated
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Comment: There's probably more in the stack trace (look for "caused by") but in any event is `com.example.linebet.Register` your code you are attempting to run ?  If so include the `onCreate` portion at a minimum.  Not much to go on but your activity is failing and likely is in the `onCreate` portion or what it calls so start with posting your activity `onCreate`.

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.example.linebet;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public abstract class Register extends AppCompatActivity {



EditText mFullName,mEmail,mPassword;
Button mRegisterBtn;
//TextView mLoginBtn;
FirebaseAuth fAuth;
////ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancesState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstancesState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


    mFullName = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
    mEmail = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName2);
    //mPhone =findViewById(R.id.);
    mPassword = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);
    mRegisterBtn = findViewById(R.id.button);
    // mLoginBtn =findViewById(R.id.);

    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    // progressBar=findViewById()

    mRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        }

    });


}
}
```

Comment: Your activity should not be `abstract` so that needs to be removed.  If there are methods that need implementing then have Studio generate the stubs for them using the menus.

Comment: i removed abstract but the problem still occuring